# CSS Background image with PHP variable?

Tags: php, css, background-image

In wordpress there is a plugin that assigns a header graphic for each page. You call that header graphic by placing this code in your header.php file:

```
<?php if(function_exists('show_media_header')){ show_media_header();} ?>
```

This basically calls the image assigned and places it as an IMG in HTML.
I would like to have it called as a background image with CSS but don't know how. For example:

```
.header-graphic{ background:url("show_media_header();"); }
```

I know that will obviously not work but that should explain what I'm trying to do.

Any help would be great.
Thanks!

Comment: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/98880/how-to-get-only-the-url-of-the-image-that-show-media-header-returns

Answer (score 2):

Depending on the scope of show_media_header() and that it actually returns the path to an image you could write the following:

```
.header-graphic{ background:url("<?php echo show_media_header(); ?>"); }
```

However this is of course under the assumption that your css is in the php-file, which wouldn't be recommended. You should look at using SASS or LESS instead.

Comment: Nop, that would result into

`.header-graphic{ background:url("<img src='something.png'>"); }`

Comment: Thanks for the help! I tried it but nothing appears? This is what I have: <style type="text/css">
  .header-graphic-background {
     background:url("<?php echo show_media_header(); ?>"); }
 </style>

Answer (score 2):

It's generally a bad idea to serve static files (like CSS) dynamically, since it can't be cached effectively.  So inserting the result of `show_media_header()` directly into your CSS is a no-go.

However, there is an alternative:  Insert *just* that style into the HTML like so:

```
<h3 style='background-image: url("<?= show_media_header(); ?>");'>
   Foo
</h3>
```

Which can then be further modified by CSS that is in a statically-served and unchanging file - for example:

```
h3 {
   background-position: left 3px top 3px;
}
```

This of course assumes the function returns just the image URL; I've not used Wordpress personally.

Based on another comment, apparently this function generates a complete `<img>` tag (ugh!) so you might instead have to do something like this:

```
<h3>
   <?= show_media_header(); ?>
   Foo
</h3>
```

And style it as appropriate like so:

```
h3 img {
   margin: 3px 0 0 3px;
}
```

Comment: Ok so would I do something like this? <div style="background-image: url("<?= show_media_header();");">  My code blows up when I do that. Don't I need to close the php tag somewhere?

Comment: @crobley Yes, I made a typo

Answer (score 1):

I'm gonna post it down here because no one is considering your statement:

"and places it as an IMG in HTML"

You may have to edit you plugin output. Since `show_media_header();` echo a value, the function itself is creating a `<img>` element. Look for the plugin file, search for the function and, either create another one, duplicating the original, something like `show_media_header_bg` where you manipulate the element, or change the original.

Comment: Heres what I found: echo '<img src="'.$dhnd_image_url_base.$load_this_media.'" alt="'.$dhnd_alt_tag.'" title="'.$dhnd_alt_tag.'" />'; How can I change that to be a background image?

Comment: You can either change it for a `echo "<div style='background-image: url(" . $dhnd_image_url_base . $load_this_media . ")' title='".$dhnd_alt_tag."'></div>"`

or you can replace that `echo` for `return  $dhnd_image_url_base . $load_this_media` and instead of call `show_header_image(); ` on header.php, you write a div or other element, with `style="background-image:url(". show_header_image_bg() . ")"`

Answer (score 0):

How about if you use descendant CSS selectors as such:

```
#page #header {
   background-image: url("image.jpg");
}

#another-page #header {
   background-image: url("another-image.jpg");
}
```

and so assign each page to its background image.

Here, I'm assuming you can grab into each page by an id (here called "page" and "another-page", and that your header template has an id of header. It would help to see some HTML to see how best to exactly achieve this via CSS.

Answer (score 0):

Got it to work!

Dug around in the plugin PHP file and found this:

```
function get_media_header_url() {
global $post;
$post_id = $post->ID;
```

So I did this:

```
.header-graphic-background{ background:url("images/<?php echo get_media_header_url() ?>"); }
```

Works great!
You guys absolutely pointed me in the right direction. THANKS!!!